# Dataframe.str Fails as entire column is blank

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have data frame with many columns. While execution i got an error like

```
Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas
```

I figured it out this is because one my column has only Nan values on that particular occasion and the .str failed on the code

```
df1['Merchant_old']=df1['Merchant_old'].str.lower().str.strip()
```

I don't how I should use isna() to run the above step only when the entire column is not blank.

Comment: `I figured it out this is because one my column has only Nan values on that particular occasion and the .str failed on the code` Wrong, `str` will work regardless.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that type of your `df.col` is `np.float`. You could get away with using `str` with `df.col.astype(np.object_).str`. This will keep `np.NaN`s in the final output.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a mask here, with `isnull` and `all`

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['A',np.nan,'B'],'B':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]})

s=df.isnull().all()
df.loc[:,s[~s].index]=df.loc[:,s[~s].index].apply(lambda x : x.str.lower().str.strip())
df
     A   B
0    a NaN
1  NaN NaN
2    b NaN
```